# How to properly adapt String.PadRight() to a string

Tags: c#

As we all know strings are [Immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)   , so I'm having an issue while I'm trying to add zeros on the right of the string

**Current issue :**

**input** : bmdNoteOrdinal ="bla bla" 
**output**:  "bla bla"

**Desired Result**

**input** : bmdNoteOrdinal ="bla bla" **Output** :   bmdNoteOrdinal ="bla bla0000000000000"

I'm aware of what I'm doing wrong , I just don't know how to fix it .

Here is my code :

```
 int paddingNbr =0;
    if (bmdNoteOrdinal.Length < 20) {
        paddingNbr = 20 - bmdNoteOrdinal.Length;
        string tempbmdNoteOrdinal = bmdNoteOrdinal.PadRight(paddingNbr, '0');
        bmdNoteOrdinal = tempbmdNoteOrdinal;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation on the string length:

```
paddingNbr = 20 - bmdNoteOrdinal.Length;
```

not only is unnecessary, but it's the cause of your problem.

```
String str = "bla bla";
Console.WriteLine(str.PadRight(20,'0')); // bla bla0000000000000
```

> Returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in this string by
>   padding them on the right with a specified Unicode character, **for a
>   specified total length**.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But  I only need to pad right if the length is below 20

Comment: If the length is greater than or equal to 20, the outcome will be unchanged.

Comment: Ahhhhhh now I understood why you mentioned  **for a specified total length.**  , thank you for considering time helping my issue

Comment: Sorry, it was unclear: I mean that if the string length is greater or equal to 20, no padding will be applied.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, please accept it :)

Comment: Of course , due to SO policy (god knows why) but there is a delay before being able to accept answers ....which explains why I took time before accepting your answer . Thanks again very professional explication and helpful

Answer (score 1):

You just need one statement to get the desired effect.

```
var bmdNoteOrdinal = "blah blah";
bmdNoteOrdinal = bmdNoteOrdinal.PadRight(20, '0');
// result: "blah blah00000000000"
```

Note that if the original string is larger than 20, then no padding is added. No need to check in advance with the `if()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that PadRight doesn't just with the characters as many times as you the int parameter is. But instead, it fills the string only with the char until the string is as long as the int value.

```
int paddingNbr = 20;
if (bmdNoteOrdinal.Length < 20) { 
string tempbmdNoteOrdinal = bmdNoteOrdinal.PadRight(paddingNbr, '0');
bmdNoteOrdinal = tempbmdNoteOrdinal; 
}
```

This should give you the desired results.

Comment: The is no need to check for the length of the array (it is done internal to `.PadRight()`) and there is no need to use a temporary variable.